# Copying string from a specific index from one file to pasting that string on a specific place in another file

Tags: python, python-3.x

My intention was to copy a piece of string after either a colon or equal sign from File 1 , and pasting that string in File 2 in a similar location after either a colon or equal sign.

For instance, if File 1 has:
username: Stack

File 2 is originally empty: 
username=

I want Stack to be copied over to File 2 after username. Currently, I'm stuck and not sure what to do. The program piece I made below doesn't copy the username. I would greatly appreciate any input!

```
with open("C:/Users/SO//Downloads//f1.txt", "r") as f1:
    with open("C:/Users/SO//Downloads//f2.txt", "r+") as f2:
        searchlines = f1.readlines()
        searchlines_f2=f2.readlines()          
        for i, line in enumerate(searchlines):
            if 'username' in line: 
                for l in searchlines[i:i+1]: 
                    ind = max(l.find(':'), l.find('='), 0) #finding index of specific characters 
                    copy_string=l[ind+1:].strip()  #copying string for file 2  
                    for l in searchlines_f2[i:i+1]:
                        if 'username' in line:
                            f2.write(copy_string)
```

Comment: Can you trust that the number of lines in each file are always the same?  Will you encounter more than one `username` instance in each file?

Comment: @JordanBonitatis The number of lines in each file are not expected to be the same, and you will not encounter more than one instance in each file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something like this will get you what you need in a more maintainable and Pythonic way.

Note the use of regex as well as some string methods (e.g., `startswith`)

```
import re

SOURCE_PATH = "C:/Users/SO//Downloads//f1.txt"
TARGET_PATH = "C:/Users/SO//Downloads//f2.txt"

def _get_lines(filepath):
    """ read `filepath` and return a list of strings """
    with open(filepath, "r+") as fh:
        return fh.readlines()    

def _get_value(fieldname, text):
    """ parse `text` to get the value of `fieldname` """
    try:
        pattern = '%s[:=]{1}\s?(.*)' % fieldname
        return re.match(pattern, text).group(1)
    except IndexError:
        # you may want to handle this differently!
        return None

def _write_target(filepath, trgt_lines):
    """ write `trgt_lines` to `filepath` """
    with open(filepath, "w+") as fh:
        fh.writelines(trgt_lines)

src_lines = _get_lines(SOURCE_PATH)
trgt_lines = _get_lines(TARGET_PATH)

# extract field values from source file
fields = ['username', 'id', 'location']
for field in fields:
    value = None
    for cur_src in src_lines:
        if cur_src.startswith(field):
            value = _get_value(field, cur_src)
            break

    # update target_file w/ value (if we were able to find it)
    if value is not None:
        for i, cur_trgt in enumerate(trgt_lines):
            if cur_trgt.startswith('{0}='.format(field)):
                trgt_lines[i] = '{0}={1}'.format(field, value)
                break
_write_target(TARGET_PATH, trgt_lines)
```

Comment: Can you explain what this line is doing? 

re.match('username[:=]{1}\s?(.*)', text).group(1)

Comment: @Neil - sure; that line is calling the `re` (i.e., regular expression) library's `match` function and returning the first match it found (the match function can search for more than one match)  Regular expressions are an extremely powerful text parsing/manipulation tool.  The pattern we are matching on, in this case, is any string with "username" followed by either exactly one colon or exactly one equal sign and 0 or more spaces and then matching everything after that pattern.  Check out this handy [cheat sheet](https://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/)

Comment: Thanks, the cheat sheet is really helpful! The program you provided makes it so that it changes spacing of the line after the username, is there a way to fix this? I have been trying to wrap my head around it for some days. And do you know if there's a way to make the `_get_username` function more generic so it can get a field name from the source file (e.g. username, ID number, etc) and the program can find the best match in the target file? I'd appreciate it if you can point me the right direction.

Comment: Sure - the language developers use when making a method more generic and less tied to something specific is "decoupling."  And we can decouple that function from "username" and paramatize it.  I will update the example, but first need to know if the other fields will use a similar pattern (e.g., the field-name followed by a colon/equal-sign, etc..)

Comment: Yes, the field names will have a similar pattern followed by a colon/equal sign.

Comment: Sweet - that makes it pretty straightforward.  I updated the answer to reflect that.